# BMI calculator assignment. c#. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#

Hi I've just started college and I have an assignment in `c#` where I have to create a BMI calculator that can calculate BMI in both metric and imperial. I have created the code below which comes up with many errors but I don't know why. Any ideas?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BMI_CALCULATOR
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int weightPounds, WeightKilo, heightMeters, heightInches, Menu;
           double BMI;



            Console.WriteLine("1. Imperial");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Metric");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Exit);
            Console.WriteLine("press 1 for Imperial, 2 for metric or 3 to exit: ");
           Menu = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Menu == 1)
            {
            Console.Write("please enter your weight in pounds: ");
            weightPounds = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.Write("please enter your height in inches: ");
            heightInches = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            BMI = weightPounds / Math.Pow (heightInches, 2);

                if (BMI < 18.5) 
                {
            Console.WriteLine("your BMI is {0:C}" , BMI, "you are underweight");
                }

             else if ((BMI >= 18.5) && (<= 24.9)) 
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("your BMI is {0:C}" , BMI, "you are normal");
                }

                else if (BMI > 24.9 )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your BMI is {0:C}" , BMI, "you are overweight");
                }

            }


            else if (Menu == 2)
            {
                  Console.Write("please enter your weight in pounds: ");
            weightPounds = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.Write("please enter your height in inches: ");
            heightInches = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            BMI = WeightKilo / Math.Pow (heightMeters, 2);

             if (BMI < 18.5)
            {

             {
                  Console.WriteLine("your BMI is {0:C}" , BMI, "you are underweight");
             }

                  else if ((BMI >= 18.5) && (<= 24.9)) 
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("your BMI is {0:C}" , BMI, "you are normal");
                }


                else if (BMI > 24.9 )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your BMI is {0:C}" , BMI, "you are overweight");
                }
            }


            else if (Menu == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("end program");

            }



            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Your job is to ask for help and that includes ERROR DESCRIPTIONS. Newbie or not. I suggest a book and reading it.

Comment: First, for calculating BMI, I would take heightinMeters in a double variable. You are taking it in int, which would result in a person only 1 meters tall (most cases)

Comment: Ok guys thanks for the constructive criticism I can see your points!

Comment: We were never thought how to convert double to string which is why I used int.

Comment: the errors seemed to pile up from else if ((BMI >= 18.5) && (<= 24.9))

Comment: it says "invalid expression of terms "(" and "<=". It also says "; expected" for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if (Menu == 2)
{
    Console.Write("please enter your weight in pounds: ");
    weightPounds = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("please enter your height in inches: ");
    heightInches = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    BMI = WeightKilo / Math.Pow (heightMeters, 2);
    //your code
}
```

Here, you are reading metric values into imperial variables, then using metric var's (already uninitialised).

If you want to parse double from string, use Double.TryParse()

Comment: thanks!!, don't know how I didn't see that!

Comment: If this seems to you as an answer, please mark my answer as answer by checking the green tick mark